# Cannot upload Ipython Notebook by drag and drop into DashBoard

Tags: uploading, jupyter-notebook

I downloaded the tarball from [this site](http://jakevdp.github.com/mpl_tutorial/_downloads/notebooks.tgz).  I selected all the notebooks in one directory and dragged them over to the IPython Notebook Dash. All of them appeared with an upload button and renaming options. So far so good.
Then this weird behaviour started. Only the files with .v2 in the filename (full name : filename.v2.ipynb) were successfully uploaded.
[Screenshot of Chromium Browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PFObf.png)

System:
Ubuntu 12.04 (23.0.1271.97-0ubuntu0.12.04.1)
Chromium Version 23.0.1271.97

I tried the following already:
 1. added .v1 to the filename
 2. renamed the file completely to a random string
 3. couldn't reproduce the error with other notebooks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing that you have IPython 0.12?

The notebooks without `v2` are probably format version *3*, which was introduced with IPython 0.13. 0.12 can't read format v3. The reason that the tarball has both is to allow for IPython 0.12 users, so you can just use those.

If you want to upgrade, the [IPython PPA](https://launchpad.net/~jtaylor/+archive/ipython) has the latest stable version. Be aware that this will update your notebooks to format v3 next time you save them.

Comment: how do I check the "format version" of the files? my ipython version is indeed `0.12.1`